# Grunt copy a single file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

What is the format to specify a single file copy for grunt copy task

```
 copy:{
        dist:{
            files:[
               {
                    expand:true,
                    cwd:'<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest:'<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/jq.min.js',
                    src: ['components/jq/dist/jq.min.js']
                }
            ]
```

if my  `yeoman.app` dir is `A` and `yeoman.dist` is `B`, this copies the file to

```
/b/scripts/jq.min.js/components/jq/dist/jq.min.js
```

what I want is copy it as `/b/scripts/jq.min.js`

how can I do this.

EDIT:
I see an issue which implements the support.
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/3

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Does this work?

```
copy: {
    dev: {
        files: [{
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/jq/dist/',
            src: 'jq.min.js',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/',
            expand: true
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose it would help to know your folder structure. Basically, what ever you have in `src` will get copied over (including folder structure).

Answer (score 5):

Copy multiple source file locations to a single destination folder use flatten.

```js
copy: {
    dev: {
        files: [{
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: ['/components/jq/dist/jq.min.js','/components/jq/dist/jq2.min.js', '/components/bs/dist/bs.js'],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/',
            expand: true,
            flatten: true
        }]
    }
}
```